# What are the valid keys in CodeNameOne List Component ListItems?

Tags: java, codenameone

What are the valid keys in CodeNameOne List Component's ListItems?

In the CodeNameOne GUI builder, you can set keys for each item in a list. The default behavior is that certain keys will cause additional behaviors, like showing icons or navigation. However, I can't seem to find any documentation for what the recognized keys are.

I know of $navigation, destination, and icon, but are there anymore keys that the default renderer and controller can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two sources:

http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-list-of-items-the-hard-way-gui-builder-renderer.html

If you use the `MultiList` then you can determine the "name" of the elements on the `MultiList` which will map directly to the keys in the entry. If you use a List then the renderer will use the names of the components within the renderer container as the values for the keys. I suggest reading [deeper in the renderer](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html) where I discuss some interesting special cases and edge cases.